# How do i Auto Adjust the height of a range of columns in excel?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

For my c# app, a user will input lines of remarks which will eventually be exported to an excel sheet. These remarks will be placed in a merged column cell(column I to L). The issue I am facing is that I always see a white space when the excel sheet is open as the contents are taking up too much vertical space. Only after manually resizing the height, then I am able to view the remarks within the cell.

I have tried these following : aRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit(); and worksheet.Columns.AutoFit();  and worksheet.Rows.AutoFit();

```
Excel.Workbook myExcelWorkbook;
Excel.Application xlsxApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Worksheet xlsht = new Excel.Worksheet();
     File.Copy(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"checklist.xlsx", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"checklist_duplicate.xlsx", true);

                string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"checklist_duplicate.xlsx;
                xlsht = xlsxApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(path).Worksheets["Acceptance"];

                // open the existing excel file //
                myExcelWorkbook = (Excel.Workbook)(xlsxApp.Workbooks._Open(path, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing));




                    xlsht.Cells[13, "I"] = Savestate.one_one_one_grouping;/*Adding remarks into the merged column cells*/
```

How do I auto-size the height of these merged columns so these remarks can be seen?

Comment: It is difficult to visualize what the problem is. I am guessing that setting the cell/range `WrapText` property to true for each cell will make sure all the text is visible in the cell. However, I am confident the text wrap and some other “AutoFit” features will be disabled when the cell is part of a “merged” group of cells. Is there some reason you do not unmerge the cells and simply make column “I” the width you want? Then the wrap text and autofit features should work.

Comment: @JohnG Thanks for your reply. I am an intern working on a project which require me to strictly follow an excel template therefore I am not allowed to edit the excel .

Comment: I am not sure if I understand… _“not allowed to edit the excel”_ …? If you can’t edit the worksheet then what’s the problem? As noted, if the cell you are adding text to is in a group of merged cells, then your code or you are going to have to adjust the row height, which is basically an “edit” on the worksheet so I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @JohnG I can only add text into cells and adjust the size of the cells, as I am working with an excel template. My app should adjust the height of the cell according to how much text the user input. I'm looking for a way to automatically adjust the cell, instead of manually.

Comment: Since the cell is part of a merged group YOU will have to calculate this row height. The "automatic adjust" stuff (in excel) is out the window for most cases when the cell is part of a merged group (which it is). As mentioned earlier, if the cell is NOT part of a merged group of cells, then setting the cells `WrapText` to true WILL automatically adjust the row height to fit the text. Just guessing you could approximate how deep to make the row depending on how many characters are in the string.

Comment: @JohnG Correct me if I'm wrong, so what you're suggesting me to do is to write some code such that it is able to count the number of characters within the merged cell. Based on the number of characters, I can sort of gauge the height of the cell?

Comment: Yes. I will not argue that its probably not the best idea, however I feel your options are limited given the requirements. Even counting the characters is going to vary quite a bit in some cases.

Comment: Thanks @JohnG, I will try to work with the suggestion you gave and update if I manage to get it to work!